# Python regex matching

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract the string with the following pattern.

```
MsgTrace(65/26)noop:user=xxx=INBOX:cmd=534
```

regex should extract noop

but when i try the follwong pattern , it extract the string "user" as well.

```
ImapFetchComplete(56/39)user=xxxxxxxxxx
```

need to output the word only contains the following pattern.

```
)somestring:  (it should extract the word somestring)

)somestring=xxxx (this shouldn't be extracted)
```

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
from subprocess import *
import os
import re

dir="/tmp/logs/"
os.chdir(dir)
for filename in os.listdir(dir):
    with open(filename) as fp:
        for line in fp:
             try:
                 print(re.search(r'\)([a-z]*?):',line).group(1))
             except:
                 pass
```

Comment: It does not look like there is a problem with the regex, see https://regex101.com/r/ImzAyW/1. It cannot match `somestring` in `)somestring=xxxx` because there is no `:`.

Comment: it out put both somestring and somestring= , in the example it output both noop and user=xxxxxxxxxx

Comment: I think your example is incomplete (because it's behaving as expected, though only by accident).  I think you want your match pattern to be `r'\)([^:]*?):user='` so that you don't end up picking up the rest of the line.  And I think you probably want to be using `re.match()` instead of `re.search()` if you're expecting the match to start at the beginning of the string.  You'll need to adjust the regex a little more if you use `re.match()` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
import re


def extract_from_string(s):
    match = re.search('(?<=\))\w*?(?=:)', s)
    return match.group(0) if match else None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s1 = 'MsgTrace(65/26)noop:user=xxx=INBOX:cmd=534'
    s2 = 'ImapFetchComplete(56/39)user=xxxxxxxxxx'
    s3 = 'foo'
    print(extract_from_string(s1))  # 'noop'
    print(extract_from_string(s2))  #  None
    print(extract_from_string(s3))  #  None
```

Comment: if you have both s1,s2 in the log, i need to extract only noop  not user=xxxxx

Comment: @TharangaAbeyseela Gotcha, simple fix. Is this okay now?